# String equality in Java

Tags: java, string, coding-style

I have seen both of these when checking the equality of two Java `String`'s:

```
// Method A
String string1;
// ...
if("MyString".equals(string1)) {
    // ...
}
```

and

```
// Method B
String string1;
// ...
if(string1.equals("MyString")) {
    // ...
}
```

My question is: which one is better and more widely used?

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the answers. I am used to doing what Peter described, though now I realize that option 1 is probably better if `null` is possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are sure that string1 can never be null then option 2 is readable and preferred. Otherwise option 1. Intention of option 1 is to avoid potential null pointer.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It's true that option 2 is more natural (variable compared against literal, and not vice versa) except when accounting for nulls.

Comment: yes please. can the gentlemen who down voted please explain why?

Comment: Not sure who down voted it, but I could see an argument again you statement of "option 2 being preferred".  In my experience option 1 is preferred because option 2 does not account for nulls as you explained.

Comment: @jzd - that is why i mentioned the pre-condition "If you are sure that string1 can never be null"

Comment: @Pangea, yes you did.  But my point is the only thing in your question that someone could take an object to is that option 2 is preferred.  Everything is true.

Comment: I always choose the first form. I don't agree that the second form is more readable, so the safety of the first form wins. Though you may *believe* you will never get a `null` reference, your code may someday be used in an unexpected way, so it's better to code defensively. (incidentally, in case you were wondering, no I didn't downvote you).

Comment: +1 to you @Neil I agree with your point of view as well. The answer to this question is subjective. I provided my opinion with enough context so that the OP can make an informed decision. I was disappointed to see people down voting without leaving a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Method B will fail with NullPointerException on null string1, whereas Method A will never throw this. Some authorities mandate this "defensive" programming. They have influenced me to do it, though it still does not come naturally!

It's also possible to write

```
if (string1 != null && string1.equals("MyString")) ...
```

though tools such as FindBugs flags this as a possible error, assuming that you should have made sure that string1 was already non-null. (Can you rely on the order of evaluation?).

So there are different schools of thought.

Answer (score 3):

Method A won't throw a null pointer exception. There is no better of the two. It depends on whether on not you want it to throw a npe (and you might want that in your overall design).

Comment: I don't think I agree with you. If string1 can be null but should not be null you should at least explicitly throw that NPE, or an IllegalArgumentException or IllegalStateException or some such. I would not argue for implicit NPE's as explicit control flow constructs by design.

Answer (score 0):

Method a does not throw `NullPointerException` and hence very convenient. It is widely used also.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are for exceptional processing and have more overhead than checking for error conditions and handling them with regular logic. If you have been programming for a decade a NPE is a cringe matter which usually indicates careless code. Avoid them by using "constant".equals(variable) and people who read your code and use it will be happier.

Answer (score -2):

The second one is more widely used. Neither is better.

It's the same idea as

```
if (1 == x)
```

<strike>but without a specific reason.</strike> but for a different reason. (Null pointer as noted by others).

Comment: This is not true. If you can not guarantee that string1 is not null you should not use equals on that string. It's therefore a better practice to do "some constant".equals(some_string) that the other way.

Comment: Not necessarily true that it's "better practice". It depends on the use case.